# Chutzpah - is it possible to integrate chutzapah test running with visual studio build

Tags: visual-studio, chutzpah

Is it possible to integrate chutzapah test running with visual studio build? 
What I mean here is - if any test fails the build fails.. .that way..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 ways of doing this:

1. install the Chutzpah test adapter on each build machine and get the running the tests in test explorer.

Then customize your msbuild scripts to run the tests.

2. Use the command line + custom msbuild task

It looks like Chutzpah has a command-line runner, so you can create a PowerShell script which gets called from your build server to run the tests. See the Chutzpah documentation for more information, but it should be chutzpah.console.exe under: Chutzpah.3.2.4\tools

Next if you want to integrate with Visual Studio build it means msbuild integration. Take a look at the [exec task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) on how to run custom commands and react based on the results